# html control gets hidden behind aspx controls

Tags: html, controls, drop-down-menu, asp.net

Please check the attached link in which i have attached screenshot. The html dropdown gets hidden behind the aspx dropdowns that i created. Is there any solution to make the dropdown list be seen on top of the aspx controls?
http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/2553/imageydn.jpg
Thanks in advance,
Geetha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit a rather nasty issue with the html drop-down listin IE. In short, it will always sit on top of most other controls, *no matter what you set z-index to*. There is no css way I know of to fix this easily.

However, the one thing that a drop-down list does not "leak through" is an IFRAME. The trick I usually use is to put an IFRAME underneath your drop-down "menu" and you should find the drop-down list no longer leaks through.

Nasty - but this is a long term IE gripe!

[Edit: to add an example, and also rephrase "put your drop-down 'menu' in an IFRAME"]

The following example illustrates the trick:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="z-index:1">
        <iframe style="position:absolute; height: 200px; width: 100px; z-index: 1"></iframe>
        <div style="position:absolute; background: pink; height: 200px; width: 100px; overflow:hidden; z-index: 2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
        <br/>
        <select style="z-index: 0;width: 200px">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
            <option>option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that if you remove the iframe from this example, you see the "leak through" problem re-appear.

Comment: My code has both aspx controls and html controls inside <div>..so does that mean, separate out the html control and put them inside a separate DIV in IFRAME?  and the rest separately.Sorry i dint understand it properly..

Comment: this is not working for me! in an individual solution it works fine, but wen i integrate it with the application it fails to work :(

Comment: that may well be because of the stacking order of other items on your page. Remember that your IFRAME must be "in front" of the html drop-down list.

Comment: so that means the control that has higher z-index than the rest comes on top of the other controls?

Comment: regarding z-index. Yes - kind-of. A higher z-index means the item is above another item, provided they are in the same stacking context. Check this out for more information: http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=OverlappingAndZIndex

Comment: no problem at all - glad to help. Of course, you could always mark my answer as accepted! :)

Comment: hi Rob, am getting the same z-index issue with a tooltip assigned to a label..it gets hidden behind the adjacent control and it is happening only in IE6..and adjusting the z-index is not helping.. Any other suggestions here?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp), although you have to set position: absolute to the element.

Comment: can u please explain this a little more..'cos am pretty new to this stuff.. z-index of the html control u mean? and wat do u mean wen u say absolute to the el?

Comment: If you wrap aspx control wrapped into div, you can just set z-index: 1 and position: absolute to the wrapper div and the same to the dropdown, except you set higher z-index value.